# Troubleshooting Azure Service Fabric: "The ServiceType was not registered within the configured timeout."

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have deployed a Web API written with .net Core to a local dev Azure Service Fabric cluster on my machine.  I have plenty of disk space, memory, etc, and the app gets deployed there.  However, success is intermittent.  Sometimes it doesn't deploy to all the nodes, and now I have it deployed to all the nodes, but within the Azure Service Fabric Manager page, I see each application in each node has an Error status with the message: "The ServiceType was not registered within the configured timeout."   I don't THINK I should have to remove and redeploy everything.  Is there some way I can force it to 're-register' the installed service type?  Microsoft docs are really really thin on troubleshooting these clusters.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way I can force it to 're-register' the installed service type?

On your local machine you can set the deployment to always remove the application when you're done debugging. However, if it's not completing in the first place I'm not sure if this workflow would still work.
[image]

Since we're on the topic, in the cloud I think you'd just have to use the Powershell scripts to first compare the existing app types and version and remove them before "updating". Since the orchestration of this is complicated I like to use tools to manage it.

In VSTS for instance there is an overwrite SameAppTypeAndVersion option.

[image]

And finally, if you're just tired of using the Service Fabric UI to remove the Application over and over while you troubleshoot it might be faster to use the icon in the system tray to reset the cluster to a fresh state.